# Add Java CI with Maven workflow to Maven project with my own dependencies

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

I have a GitHub repo with this three Maven projects inside:

- Client
- Server
- Engine

I want to apply the Java CI with Maven workflow, the configuration is this one:

```yaml
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven, and cache/restore any dependencies to improve the workflow execution time
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-maven
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.
name: Java CI with Maven
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven
      - name: Build with Maven -> Client
        run: mvn -B package --file client/pom.xml
      - name: Build with Maven -> Engine
        run: mvn -B package --file engine/pom.xml
      - name: Build with Maven -> Server
        run: mvn -B package --file server/pom.xml
      # Optional: Uploads the full dependency graph to GitHub to improve the quality of Dependabot alerts this repository can receive
      - name: Update dependency graph
        uses: advanced-security/maven-dependency-submission-action@571e99aab1055c2e71a1e2309b9691de18d6b7d6
```

The problem comes with the Server pom, looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.victorpiles.escacs</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.victorpiles.escacs</groupId>
            <artifactId>engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So the Server has the Engine as a dependency and GitHub can't resolve this dependency.

The pom of the Engine is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.victorpiles.escacs</groupId>
    <artifactId>engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The following error is thrown when running the Workflow:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< org.victorpiles.escacs:server >--------------------
[INFO] Building server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Warning:  The POM for org.victorpiles.escacs:engine:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.282 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-20T15:12:47Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal on project server: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.victorpiles.escacs:server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.victorpiles.escacs:engine:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project should have been a multi-module project.

Put a `pom.xml` into the root directory of the project which lists the other directories as `<modules>`. Then you build the root POM and everything will be build automatically, with resolved dependencies.